# chatbot: how to correctly determine intents?

Tags: python, chatbot

What are the usual techniques to determine the difference between the following intents, for example?

1. What is the current temperature?
   In this case, the straight-up response will be the current temperature.
2. Is current temperature 22 degrees?
   In this case, the appropriate response would be yes or no.

I am building a closed-domain chatbot (eg Siri) and am wondering if there are any techniques in Python that I can read about.

Comment: Check if it has a number in it

Comment: I should have been clear - that was just an example. It could be a question which doesn't have any number but its still a type 2 question.

Comment: This is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score -1):

I once got into programming trying to understand how bots work. What a little world. I barely remember how I did mine but let's assume you build the chat based on events that your bot can read. A very basic way to determine what to answer to each event would be a huge list of IF ELIF stuff with nested behaviours (ideally split into methods).

```
def handleevent (message, user, date, font, whatever):
    if "current temperature" in message:
        send_text_to_chat("The temperature is 22 degrees")
    elif "is current temperature" in message and "?" in message:
        specific_temp_asked(message)
    elif "potato" in message: # you could do hundred of behaviours, and nested ones.
        if user == "apple":
            send_text_to_chat("Hi apple!")
        else:
            send_text_to_chat("I am a potato bot")
    elif "who am I?" in message: # example using the event data
        send_text_to_chat("you are " + user)
    else:
        send_text_to_chat("Be more specific")
```

And then you would have to code each of the specific situations like this:

```
def specific_temp_asked(message):
    temperature = None
    split_message = message.split(" ")
    for i in split_message:
        try:
            int(i)
            temperature = i
            break
        except:
            pass
    if not temperature == None:
        real_temperature = check_temp(somehow)
        if real_temperature == temperature:
            send_text_to_chat("Yes")
        else:
            send_text_to_chat("Nope")
```

**Final note:** This is by no means the best way to do it, but if you are learning I'll get the work done without being too complicated, and then you improve the code slowly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to respond. After posting the question, I tried this on Siri (not sure how Cortana (or other bots) fare) but it responded to both questions with the same response. So, may be I was over-thinking, or may be not.

Comment: A bot will give you answers as much precise as you code it. My bot had at a time 2500 possible answers, then I got bored of it. But for each of those 2500 it had an specific reason to answer. The trick is to use keywords. For example if "temperature" is detected, he'll tell you the temp, regardless of what you truly asked. You could also store several answers for the same question and randomize the one picked.